# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method progressbar error

Tags: android, static-methods

I am new to Android , I am trying to add a progreessbar. Below is the code

```
 progressbar("test");

public void  progressbar(String test) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
```

If I run this I get following error
"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method progressbar(String) from the type MainActivity  MainActivity.java   /ProgressBar2/src/com/example/progressbar2  line 64 Java Problem"

Anyone knows about this?

Comment: you have to execute `progressbar("test");` inside a method.

Comment: `public void static progressbar(String text)` must fix the issue.

Comment: replace "ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this)" with "ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);" and if progressbar is in seperate class, pass context + string

Comment: Conbine the above anwers  hope this will solve your issue